# YouTube logs me in automatically

Tags: authentication, youtube, gmail, google-account

Lately I've been seeing some weird behaviour when accessing YouTube from my laptop. For some reason i'm **always logged in**.

Now, i have a laptop and a desktop and in the last few months I've only used this laptop for accessing my mails (Gmail) and checking SE, I use my desktop for YouTube, mail, programming, ...

I do not understand why I'm always logged in, even when I never enter my credentials. So I've tried a few things but nothing worked so far (to remain logged out):

1. Specifically logging out, re-open browser (Firefox) and I'm still logged
   in
2. Clearing all remembered passwords
3. Clearing all cookies
4. Using Internet Explorer (lord forgive me)

I do not use Chrome or any other google applications.

So my question is: how does YouTube still know my account and logs me in each time I visit their website, despite the things I did above and can I somehow disable it? (depending on whatever technique is used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube uses your Gmail session to log you in.

This is because your Youtube account is linked to your Gmail account, you can unlink them if the Youtube account has been creating prior to May 2009 - [Unlink my YouTube account from a Google Account](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183819).

Note that you will need to link another Gmail account to your Youtube account.

Comment: Hah that's nifty, although unwanted in my case, thanks !